# Delete request works on Postman and api docs but not with axis

Tags: axios, react-native, http-delete

I would like to delete a set of data from my array. However, it works perfectly on Postman and api docs but throws  **[Error: Request failed with status code 307]**  when I try it on axios. Below is what my code looks like:

```
 axios.delete(`http://143.198.67.65:8000/events/42`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was add a trailing slash to the URL. The endpoint had it, but due to an oversight, I missed it.